# Script in Bash to delete

Tags: bash

I am trying to delete all files containing the name TRAR in the filename. This is for a Linux system and this is my first time doing such a script, below is what I have tried, but it does not work

```
cd /appl/virtuo/gways/input_d
rm -rf TRAR*
```

When I manually enter the directory and run rm -rf TRAR* , all the files are removed, I need this script to work so that it can be added to run via a cronjob..

```
VENDOR=ericsson-msc
RELEASE=R13.2
BASE_DIR=/appl/virtuo/gways
RAW_DIR=${BASE_DIR}/config/${VENDOR}/${RELEASE}/trdipfile_raw_landing_area

#rm -rf $RAW_DIR/*

 cd ${RAW_DIR}

ssh netperf@10.76.26.1 "cd /var/opt/ericsson/sgw/outputfiles/apgfiles/oms ; find . -newer ~/msc-              trdif-timestamp -type f | egrep TRDIP | cpio -oc ; touch ~/msc-trdif-timestamp" 2>/dev/null | cpio -   icdu 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Do you have the Bash processor line at the top: `#!/bin/bash` ?

Comment: You could just put the line `rm -rf /appl/virtuo/gways/input_d/TRAR*` in the crontab file

Comment: I actually need to add this part in to this script written by someone else, I have added the script at the top, I am quite confused as this is my first time writing such a script

Answer (score 0):

If you run this script by crontab then you should add

`!#/bin/sh` to first line of file. Anc change permissions for this file. For example

```
chmod 755 script.sh
```

Or you can add to crontab command as `/bin/sh /<folder with scripts>/script.sh`

Comment: I dont think this option is viable

Comment: Agreed with @user2586302. Also ! and # are around the wrong way.